# String index not working? - Python

Tags: python, string

I'm Making a sort of cipher that requires a string to be read backwards and i get an indexing error even though the index I reference is well within range:

```
M = str(input("Input Message: "))
M = M.upper()
L = len(M)
A = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]

def DECRYPT():
    global L
    global M
    global A

    if L%2 != 0:
        POS = False
    else:
        POS = True

    i = L-1
    NM = ""
    while 1:
        if M[i] != " ":
            INDEX = A.index(M[i])
            if POS == True:
                INDEX += (i + 1)
            else:
                INDEX -= (i)
            INDEX %= 26        
            NM = NM+A[INDEX]
            i += 1
            if POS == True:
                POS = False
            else:
                POS = True
    print("\n"+NM)

def ENCRYPT():
    global L
    global A
    global M

    POS = True
    M = M[::-1]
    i = 0
    NM = ""

    while 1:
        if i == L:
            break
        if M[i] != " ":
            INDEX = A.index(M[i])
            if POS == True:
                INDEX += (i + 1)
            else:
                INDEX -= (i + 1)
            INDEX %= 26        
            NM = NM+A[INDEX]
        i += 1
        if POS == True:
            POS = False
        else:
            POS = True
    print("\n"+NM)

while 1:
    C = int(input("\nWhat do you want to do:\n1) Encrypt Something\n2)Decrypt Something\n\n"))
    if C == 1:
            ENCRYPT()
    if C == 2:
            DECRYPT()
```

where i is a placeholder value. I run it and get this:

```
Input Message: ABC

What do you want to do:
1) Encrypt Something
2)Decrypt Something

2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Danny\Google Drive\SHIFT.py", line 67, in <module>
    DECRYPT()
  File "C:\Users\Danny\Google Drive\SHIFT.py", line 19, in DECRYPT
    if M[i] != " ":
IndexError: string index out of range
```

I have tried changing value of i to no avail.

Comment: `REST OF CODE` is causing the error

Comment: `String` is empty presumably

Comment: The error is happening in the parts of the code you are not showing.

Comment: Could you give some more code? This looks correct but maybe you stripped out the part that poses a problem. Also, stylewise: in Python, write your variables like this `var_name` and not `VarName`. The latter is used for classes

Comment: If you have an empty string e.g: `String = ''` then the value of the assignment `i = len(String) - 1` is -1. There's no offset, positive or negative in an empty string so `String[i]` which is the same as `String[-1]` will yield `IndexError: string index out of range`

Comment: Example here: https://eval.in/676694 In summary, you might want to add code to validate the length of `String` is one that you expect. You're asserting that `String` is not empty - so as pointed out by others, there must be other parts of your code that you have not shown changing this.

Comment: [Catch the exception](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) and print out any relevant variables to get a handle on what is happening; then add strategically placed print statements to find where it is happening.  What are ```M``` and ```i``` when the exception occurs?

Comment: The while loop was causing i to become negative. Now i just have to deal with a logic error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems with your code: as fernand0 noted, your index runs the wrong way; your inversion of `POS` happens at different levels in the code, the encryptor does it on every character, the decryptor does it on every letter -- they should work the same; five of your six global declarations aren't needed; you don't deal with word breaks correctly so the decryption won't match the original; once you encrypt, there's no way to decrypt in the same session as the local `NM` doesn't feedback into the global `M`.

Below is my rework of your code addressing the above problems and some style issues.  The key phrase here is 'simplify'.  I've kept your odd uppercase variable names but expanded them from single characters to what they represent:

```
MESSAGE = input("Input Message: ").upper()
ALPHABET = list("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
ALPHABET_LENGTH = len(ALPHABET)

def DECRYPT(MESSAGE):

    LENGTH = len(MESSAGE)
    IS_NEGATIVE = True

    NEW_MESSAGE = ""

    for I in range(LENGTH):

        if MESSAGE[I] in ALPHABET:
            INDEX = ALPHABET.index(MESSAGE[I])
            if IS_NEGATIVE:
                INDEX -= (I + 1)
            else:
                INDEX += (I + 1)
            INDEX %= ALPHABET_LENGTH
            NEW_MESSAGE += ALPHABET[INDEX]

            IS_NEGATIVE = not IS_NEGATIVE
        else:
            NEW_MESSAGE += MESSAGE[I]

    return NEW_MESSAGE[::-1]

def ENCRYPT(MESSAGE):

    MESSAGE = MESSAGE[::-1]

    LENGTH = len(MESSAGE)
    IS_POSITIVE = True

    NEW_MESSAGE = ""

    for I in range(LENGTH):

        if MESSAGE[I] in ALPHABET:
            INDEX = ALPHABET.index(MESSAGE[I])
            if IS_POSITIVE:
                INDEX += (I + 1)
            else:
                INDEX -= (I + 1)
            INDEX %= ALPHABET_LENGTH
            NEW_MESSAGE += ALPHABET[INDEX]

            IS_POSITIVE = not IS_POSITIVE
        else:
            NEW_MESSAGE += MESSAGE[I]

    return NEW_MESSAGE

while True:
    print("\nWhat do you want to do:")
    print("1) Encrypt Message")
    print("2) Decrypt Message")

    CHOICE = int(input("\n"))

    if CHOICE == 1:
        MESSAGE = ENCRYPT(MESSAGE)
    if CHOICE == 2:
        MESSAGE = DECRYPT(MESSAGE)

    print("\n" + MESSAGE)
```

**TEST**

```
> python3 file.py
Input Message: An opportunity to teach is an opportunity to learn

What do you want to do:
1) Encrypt Message
2) Decrypt Message

1

OPDAQ HB OEWAGIBFXIU JD RI JZEZZ GC NFVBFJAGWJT KC

What do you want to do:
1) Encrypt Message
2) Decrypt Message

2

AN OPPORTUNITY TO TEACH IS AN OPPORTUNITY TO LEARN

What do you want to do:
1) Encrypt Message
2) Decrypt Message
```

Answer (score 0):

You are starting i at the end of the string and then, you are increasing it. I think the line             i += 1 should be i -= 1

Comment: I have corrected the syntax but it had no effect on the error

Comment: Well, there are more issues. You decrement i only when you enter in the if, so this is a problem. Moreover, the condition in the while is 1, so the i will become, eventually -1 and this is out of range. Try putting         print("i",i,L-1)
under the while 1 and you will see what's happening.